# SELECT statement inside a CASE statement in SNOWFLAKE

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a query where i have "TEST"."TABLE" LEFT JOINED to PUBLIC."SchemaKey". Now in my final select statement i have a case statement where i check if c."Type" = 'FOREIGN' then i want to grab a value from another table but the table name value i am using in that select statement is coming from the left joined table column value. I've tried multiple ways to get to work but i keep getting an error, although if i hard code the table name it seems to work. i need the table name to come from c."FullParentTableName". Is what i am trying to achieve possible in snowflake and is there a way to make this work ? any help would be appreciated !

```
SELECT 
c."ParentColumn",
c."FullParentTableName",
a."new_value",
a."column_name"
CASE WHEN c."Type" = 'FOREIGN' THEN (SELECT "Name" FROM TABLE(c."FullParentTableName") WHERE "Id" = 'SOME_ID') ELSE null END "TestColumn" -- Need assistance on this line...
FROM "TEST"."TABLE" a
LEFT JOIN (
    select s."Type", s."ParentSchema", s."ParentTable", s."ParentColumn", concat(s."ParentSchema",'.','"',s."ParentTable",'"') "FullParentTableName",s."ChildSchema", s."ChildTable", trim(s."ChildColumn",'"') "ChildColumn"
    from PUBLIC."SchemaKey" as s
    where s."Type" = 'FOREIGN'
    and s."ChildTable" = 'SOMETABLENAME'
    and "ChildSchema" = 'SOMESCHEMANAME'
) c
on a."column_name"  = c."ChildColumn"
```

Thanks !

Comment: How many values of "FullParentTableName" are there? If only 2 or 3 you could join to them all.

Comment: There are about 2.  But doing more joins i think wouldn’t be optimal.  Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: You'd do better to add 2 or 3 tables to the join than to run a sub query in every row.

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake you cannot dynamically use the partial results as tables.

You can use a single bound value via [identifier](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html) to bind a value to table name

But you could write a Snowflake Scripting but it would need to explicitly join the N tables. Thus if you N is fixed, you should just join those.